# how to build data model in Shark machine learning API

Tags: machine-learning, data-modeling, shark-ml

My senario is: I have different numbers points(x,y,z) for every subject.
for example, for subject1, I have an evaluated value 100, and this subject has 5 points:(1,2,3),(4,2,3),(1,5,4),(3,2,3),(8,2,1).  
for subject2, I have an evaluated value 40, and this subject has 2 points:(4,7,3),(2,2,0).

And I have prepared 100 subjects for machine learning.  
I have searched for machine learning data model. Generally, the imported data just has one point for each subject, for example  x1,x2,x3 =>y.  But it doesn't fit my situation.

Does anyone have any ideas?  
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch is this doesn't clear? how? I have clearly post my scenario, my problem, and my concerns.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Usually these sorts of questions are accompanied by some sort of code showing how you have tried to, or maybe how you would hope to, codify this problem in the language/library of your choice.  I am not an expert on Machine Learning, and my comment was only intended to help educate you on how things work on this site, to hopefully increase your odds of getting a good answer.

Comment: @StephenRauch  thank you,